# How can I add my query parameter data -which I use in URL- to my response data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

I'm sending a request to get organization data's from API firstly, then ı getting another specific data's -which is **"plants"**- from another API with sending as a parameter **organizationEIC** property of my **organization** data which ı get in the first request. I am doing this to get for each plants of each organizations. What ı want to do is, I need to add **organizationEIC** property which ı use in the URL query to the response data's which are came as a result of my request. Let me make this clear with one **example**;
I am sending a request like **https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/service/production/dpp-injection-unit-name?organizationEIC=40X000000000104H and as you can see it responses to me with **5 different plant data**. I need to add the organizationEIC property -which ı use for get this 5- to this 5 response data and save like this to database to record which organization they are affiliated with. In another request with a different organizationEIC code, maybe it gets **2 plant data**, so ı need to add my organizationEIC to this 2 plant data. So how can ı get this data from url to add my result datas in foreach loop?
I hope ı explained my problem clear and easy to understand. So here is **my codes**;

```
var datas = []
var result = []
var plantList = []
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    companies: [],

    plants: []
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/service/production/dpp-organization', {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      }
    })
      .then(response =>
        response.json())
      .then(async resultJson => {
        this.setState({
          companies: resultJson.body.organizations,
        })
        await this.getPlants(resultJson.body.organizations)   //first get org. datas and send as param.
      });
  }
  getPlants = async (items) => {
    const data = await Promise.all(items.map((plant) => {     //getting plants for each organization
      return fetch(`https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/service/production/dpp-injection-unit-name?organizationEIC=${plant.organizationETSOCode}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'           
        }
      }).then(response =>response.json())              //need some logic for my solution here probably :(
    }))
    data.forEach(element => {
      datas.push(element.body.injectionUnitNames)
    });
  
    Array.prototype.push.apply(plantList, this.configure(datas))
    this.setState({
      plants: plantList
    })
  }
  
  configure = (units) => {
    units.forEach((unit) => {
      unit.forEach((item) => {
        result.push(item)
      })
    })
    return result
  }
```

I am open for any tips and tricks, thx in advance for your helps and advices :)

Comment: if I understood your question correctly, you can try the below snippet after fetching the data  in getPlants method.
`.then(response => {return response.json().map(item => {
     item[organizationEIC] = plant.organizationETSOCode; 
     return item; 
})})`

I'm not sure if you might have already tried this, but this might solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your comment. But unfortunately you understand me wrong. the response data don't have the defaultly property to include organizationETSOCode. I have a row in database named  organizationETSOCode and need to bind this in backend and save there. organizationEIC is something like plantId and needs to stay constant

Answer (score 0):

Add another `then()` to your `fetch()`  and map the data with the new property

Something like:

```
const data = await Promise.all(items.map((plant) => {     //getting plants for each organization
      const {organizationETSOCode} =plant;
      return fetch(`https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/service/production/dpp-injection-unit-name?organizationEIC=${organizationETSOCode}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'           
        }
      }).then(response =>response.json())
        .then(data=> data.map(o => ({...o, organizationETSOCode})))             
    }))
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't accept data as an array so gives 'data.map is not a function' error because data is just a single result of the request. so ım going to try to edit your advice to my current code

Comment: Wasn't sure what `data` actually looked like. Is it just an object?

Comment: yes when ı console log data like this in second then `.then(data => console.log(data))` it gives every single response of requests and also gives **Cannot read property 'body' of undefined** error so its also effects the response.json() which in first .then i think :)

Comment: Is it even returning JSON? Link in question is to xml resource

Comment: yes it shows xml but gets as a json so there is no problem about getting data with the codes which ı mentioned in the question.

Comment: the thing that makes me think the most is, my response data doesn't have a property to keep organizationETSOCode value (as you can see when you click the link). How can ı connect and set this organizationETSOCode data to response data ?

Comment: You do it by modifying what you receive like I did in second then()

Comment: okey, ım trying to modify my codeblocks according to your advice and sample, I will also inform you about the result. Thx for your help :)

Comment: Hello again @charlietfl. I modified your advice to my code and have a solution successfully. Here is my solution in second then().  `.then(resultJson => ({...resultJson.body.injectionUnitNames.map((item)=>{ return ({...item,organizationETSOCode})`  Editing your answer like this would be correct for the other users. Have and nice day without covid :)